# C# - error : Unable to read the project file

Tags: c#

Have a bigSmall problem here.
I cant open any type of project in visual studios. Even when i creating a new one I get the error:

**C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 
The element <#text> beneath element  is unrecognized.**

When I choose to open a SLN file or open trough File>Open>Project/Solution I get an other error:

**One or more projects in the solution  were not loaded correctly.
Please see the Output Window for details.**

Anyone knows? Seen some solutions on the net but it doesnt seem they help me with this.

Thanks.

<>

I have reinstalled Visual Studios but the bug remain.. Seriously. Ripping my hair of. Really need this to work!

Comment: What details are there in the Output Window?

Comment: Is this a fresh install, if not, what has changed since it was working? First i'd try re-installing visual studio.

Comment: Oh sorry! Missed your comment.
COPYPASTE:

C:\Users\User\Dropbox\dropbox\Projekt och viktiga saker kanske typ\CRM Alpha(Debug)\CRM\CRM-Rick.csproj : error  : Unable to read the project file 'CRM-Rick.csproj'. 
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.CSharp.targets(114,5): The element <#text> beneath element <Target> is unrecognized.

StackOF always has a solution, so I wanted to wait on a couple of answers before i uninstalled.

Anyways, waiting a bit to uninstall, if someone has THE solution. Or I will RAGEQUIT this. ;) Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you maybe installed a Plugin that make problem?

Comment: I got resharper. But I remember now that i once added a random plugin to sort out empty spaces (think it was for resharper?). BUt that was a while ago. When my friend share our object via Dropbox, the SLN file gets a notepadicon, with a margin of white on all sides (Like the notepad icon is posted at a paper, like it the wrong format). The SOU file gets the visual studios icon on a paper, ("unlimited sign"). This suck coz I have a big project to get ready for Friday, haha. Perfect timing ;)

Comment: I have done a real uninstall of all components that even include programming. So all SQL, xml and whatsonot is gone. Reinstalled, got same error. Changed in target file. Now I get reference problems.

Comment: you said on a other machine (from a friend) it works? Get you the error only in that project or in every project you want open?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. What I did was replace the `ControldeMenu.csproj` that is found in the project directory, for a backed-up copy, that was what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled and reinstalled the .NET framework and resolved the issue.